# IronPython: SetVariable array2D in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, ironpython

I'm making a software to use a Python script (IronPython) in c#.
The code is:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
...
...
    private void RunScript()
    {
        ScriptEngine engine;
        ScriptRuntime runtime;
        ScriptSource source = null;
        ScriptScope scope;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            runtime = engine.Runtime;
            runtime.IO.SetOutput(ms, Encoding.ASCII);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pythonResult.AppendText("Initialization IronPython: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(CodeTextBox.Text, SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
            scope = runtime.CreateScope();

            float[,] array2D = new float[10, 10];
            scope.SetVariable("var2", array2D);

            CompiledCode compil = source.Compile();
            compil.Execute(scope);

            byte[] arr_byte = ms.ToArray();
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arr_byte);
            pythonResult.AppendText(text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pythonResult.AppendText("Code error: " + ex.Message + "\n");
            return;
        }
    }
```

When I go to interpret the code:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
  for j in range(1, 10):
     var2[i,j] = 15.20
```

I get the following error: Can not widen from source type to target type either because the source is not a primitive type or the conversion can not be accomplished.

I have noticed that the compilation does not return errors when:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
  for j in range(1, 10):
     var2[i,j] = integer number (example var2[i,j] = 15)
```

Why this error?

Is there a way for to assign a float value to var2 without error?

Thanks for your help